# Broken connection with Firebird database from ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, firebird2.5

I'm developing desktop application based on Firebird 2.5 database in WPF / .NET Framework 4.7.2.

I have API to this application in ASP.NET Core 2.2.

In the API, I'm using the same database which:

- FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient  7.1.1
- FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird 7.1.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.4

API is running on IIS Server.

Mobile devices (up to 20) connect to this API (HTTP/JSON).

Sometimes all request with updates / deletion stop working with an error:

```
---------- MAIN EXCEPTION ---------------

Typ wyjątku: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
Wiadomosć błędu: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
TargetSite: Void Execute(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection)
Source: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
HResult: -2146233088
StackTrace:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)


---------- INNER EXCEPTION ---------------

Typ wyjątku: FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException
Wiadomosć błędu: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -206
Column unknown
P0
At line 2, column 10
TargetSite: FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataReader ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior)
Source: FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
HResult: -2147467259
StackTrace:    at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)


------------ INNER EXCEPTION ------------

Typ wyjątku: FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException
Wiadomosć błędu: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -206
Column unknown
P0
At line 2, column 10
TargetSite: Void ProcessResponse(FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.IResponse)
Source: FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
HResult: -2146233088
StackTrace:    at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ProcessResponse(IResponse response)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadResponse[TResponse]()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version11.GdsStatement.Prepare(String commandText)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.Prepare(Boolean returnsSet)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean returnsSet)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

When this error occurs once, all update / delete requests stop working.
Select statements still work.

After restarting the website, the requests start to work normally again. This situation occurs from 0 to a few times a day.

I trying to reproduce on development machine, and sometimes I noticed that another errors are showing before this error:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
> invalid request BLR at offset 55
> undefined parameter number

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
> lock conflict on no wait transaction
> deadlock update conflicts with concurrent update
> concurrent transaction number is 5863195

I can reproduce this error with simultaneous run of the same request, but in client environment, they are editing this same table but not the same rows.

I assume that can be situations when one device can send two request at the same time to update the same data (background thread + user thread).

All queries and updates are creating with this same approach:

```
using (var db = DbContext(connextionString))
{
    // do changes 
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Can somebody give a hint where the problem is?

Comment: Looks like EF Core or Firebird provider generates bad SQL. Have you tried to update EF Core? EF Core 2 is on End of Life.

Comment: I don't try upgrade libraries. It was strage to me, that at most a time EF geneerate good queries. When I try to reproduce I send the same data all the time in loop. At the begginig queries works, but after some time generates error in each query.

Comment: Looks like multithreading issue and probably in Firebird provider.

Comment: I upgrade asp.core and firebird provider and now I can not reproduce this issue. Please give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Svyatoslav  proposed I was upgraded asp.core to version 3.1 and Entity Framework to version 3.1.32 and Firebird libraries to version 7.10.1.
After upgrade I cant't  reproduce the problem.